# Can a hacker set a PHP session variable?

Tags: php, security, session

Part of the security check I set up is the random generation of an integer as a security token stored as a `$_SESSION` variable. This is validated through specific scripts and sets a boolean to true or false depending on if it's been validated (allowing entry to the site if other checks are passed). Is it possible for a hacker to somehow set this session variable? If so, how?

Comment: If a hacker can set a session variable, he could also download or modify all of your code. It's unlikely that sessions would be a target.

Comment: In general not. But there may be a vulnerability in the application that allows something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you let them, [like Joomla did](https://github.com/compoterhacker/joomlol) (see also: [the write-up for CVE-2015-8562](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/12/remote-command-execution-vulnerability-in-joomla.html)).

If your application doesn't let attackers control the contents of the `$_SESSION` superglobal, then they quite simply cannot control them. Out of the box, this cannot happen.

Other ways an attacker can control the contents of `$_SESSION`:

- You store session data in a database driver, and you fail to connect to it over TLS or SSH.
- You serialize and store session data in a cookie, then fail to properly implement cryptographically secure message authentication.

But in general, no.